# How to implement this widget?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

On the homepage of [World of Warships](http://worldofwarships.eu/en/media/) I have seen a nice Widget that allows the user to flip left and right through different "Views" (I guess it's a customized GWT-widget (Google Web Toolkit), but I'm, not sure). 
When flipping some neat animation is shown.
How to implement this on Android (code sample/snippet/demo etc.) with a `ViewPager`, `ViewPagerAdapter` or depracated `Gallery`, etc. for API level > 14 (maybe with AppCompat support) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search *coverflow*. I give you some references
[FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)
[CoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)